# Why does Jest error with Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded When I Import KnockoutJS Into A ViewModel I'm Testing?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, babeljs

I'm trying to write some tests using Jest for a KnockoutJs Project.

Apologies for any terminology I get wrong below I'm coming back to JS after about 10 years of not using it and still getting my head round things like ES6 modules.

The tests work fine until I need to test a ViewModel that uses knockout observable objects, I've added an import to my viewmodel to bring in KnockoutJs using ES6 module syntax and have babel setup to compile this so it should work in node.

My viewmodel looks like this...

```
export { myVm }
import * as ko from 'knockout'

function myVm() {
    var self = this;

    self.helloWorld = function () { return "Hello World" }

    return self;
}
```

Then my test file looks like...

```
import * as vm from '../src/viewModels/myVm'

test('Returns Hello World', () => {
    expect(vm.myVm().helloWorld()).toBe('Hello World');
});
```

When I execute Jest I get a Maximum call stack size exceeded error

[image: Error Screenshot]

If I remove the import * as ko line from my ViewModel it works fine but then I can't reference any of the object types in the knockout library.

Not sure if it's relevant but my .babelrc looks like this...

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env"
    ]
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong when I'm importing Knockout into the ViewModel?

Edit : This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "blah",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "knockout": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Its a long shot but maybe try 
`helloWorld = () => 'Hello World' `
maybe throw in a debugger too to see what the call stack looks like when you comment out that import and when you put it back, I have a feeling two functions are inadvertently calling back to one another.

Comment: I just can't put my finger on what could be the source of it :/ maybe babel or knockout are doing something under the hood that affects the other creating a recursive call or something...

Comment: @Gavin I have tried to reproduce your problem, but it seems to be working as expected. Can you try to [reproduce it here](https://github.com/Teneff/so-maximum-call-stack)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using an older than Babel 7 version and it looks like it has issues when importing `* as ko` syntax.

You can either upgrade to [Babel 7](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration) and everything will work as you have it, or just change:

```
import * as ko from 'knockout'
```

to:

```
import ko from 'knockout'
```

**Upgrating Babel**

There are a lot of resources on how to upgrade Babel, but it's not hard. Instal latest Babel [`@babel/core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/core) and [`@babel/preset-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-env):

```
npm install -D @babel/core @babel/preset-env

// OR

yarn add @babel/core @babel/preset-env --dev
```

and then change the contents of `.babelrc` to have the new `@babel/preset-env` like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can omit the `target`, but you should always use it to minimize what polyfills are included:

```
{
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
}
```

Comment: Ah! This makes sense. If it fixes the issue definitely deserves the bounty!

Comment: I've added my package.json to the question I don't reference babel directly so not sure how to update it. However switching from the * import to named does work. Any advice as to how to update babel indirectly is much appreciated but I'll also accept this as answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not hard. I have updated my answer to include minimal Babel 7 install and configuration